# Extracting tuple indices

Tags: python, kinect

I recently got hold of kinect. I'm using the python wrapper to play around. Now there are 2 functions which give the depth and the RGB values of a particular frame. I wish to extract all the rgb values which have a depth value of say greater than 'd'

```
(depth,_) = sync_get_depth()
(rgb,_) = sync_get_video()
```

I iterate through each and every value of depth and then find out the index and use it with rgb. Is there an easy way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the Python kinect wrapper, so I can't tell you which library functions to use. But you should look at the `zip` function:

```
depths = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
colors = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

# Colors with an even depth
[color for depth, color in zip(depths, colors) if depth % 2]
```

Given a some iterables, `zip` returns tuples containing successive elements from each of them.

Comment: It gave me an error saying
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: I used  
`for i range(x):
  for j in range(y):
   if depth[i,j] > 500:
    final_color[i,j] = depth[i,j]`

It takes a hell lot of time but